# Karma loading files in the wrong order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

I am about to use *Karma* to run my tests. However, it seems like the javascript files are being loaded in the wrong order.

This is where I load my files:

```
files: [
  'vendor/angular.min.js',
  'vendor/angular-mocks.js',
  'app.js',
  'modules/*.js',
  'modules/*/*.js'
],
```

However, that results in the following error:

```
Chrome 35.0.1916 (Mac OS X 10.10.0) ERROR
  Uncaught ReferenceError: AuthenticationModule is not defined
  at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/client/app/js/modules/authentication/AuthenticationController.js:1
```

I assume this is because *AuthenticationModule.js* is loaded **after** *AuthenticationController.js*. (They are placed in the same folder)

How can I load these files in the correct order, without having to type them in manually?

Comment: I had a similar problem and after all the easiest solution was to bundle my JS files into one and all problems went away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `grunt-contrib-concat` to merge the files. Did the trick :-)